# dpymenus, discord.py how to get the currently selected page in a menu

Tags: discord.py

How would I get the currently open page in dpymenus, eg page 2 in this example

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from dpymenus import Page, PaginatedMenu


class Demo(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def demo(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        page1 = Page(title='Page 1', description='First page test!')
        page1.add_field(name='Example A', value='Example B')

        page2 = Page(title='Page 2', description='Second page test!')
        page2.add_field(name='Example C', value='Example D')

        page3 = Page(title='Page 3', description='Third page test!')
        page3.add_field(name='Example E', value='Example F')

        menu = PaginatedMenu(ctx)
        menu.add_pages([page1, page2, page3])
        await menu.open()


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Demo(client))
```

also what should this be tagged with?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the answer:
use `menu.page` it will return something like `Page 1 Title`
you can use `menu.page.index` to get the index of the page item.

I found the answer in a discord server, I was not able to find any info in https://dpymenus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ if you can please tell me.